# Command line 7Zip to create archive without extension

Tags: command-line, console, 7-zip, command-line-arguments, arguments

If I specify full extensionless result path 7zip adds one corresponding to the type of created archive.
How can I make it name the result file exactly as I have specified in command line argument?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is your command line?

When you want no extension you could use `filename.` as filename.
(Note the dot at the end)

```
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z" a -tzip zip_filename. source_directory\*
```